# Cannot get list of groups users in AD - memberOf function not working

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

This query works fine:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=*) )
```

but any ever, with selection of group - with no result

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=myGroup) )

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=myGroup) )

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=myGroup) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `memberof` attribute stores dn values, so you have to provide a dn in the filter.

And by dn I mean a full dn all the way to the root of the ldap directory tree.

If your group : `CN=myGroup` is in the branch `ou=groups` and the baseDn of your directory is `dc=local,dc=com`, you have to specify a filter like :

`memberof=CN=myGroup,ou=groups,dc=local,dc=com`

Comment: Bingo! Thank you!
Key moment - **,ou=groups**